# Need make this code without JQuery, in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Who can help me make this code without JQuery because I don't know how to make this without JQuery.

```
missClick(event){

    const parentDiv = $(event.target).parent();

    $('body').off().on('click', (e) => {
        if (parentDiv.find(e.target).length === 0) {
            alert('miss click');
            $('body').off();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have use `addEventListener('click', missClick)`

```
function missClick(event){
    const parentDiv = event.target.parentElement;

    document.body.removeEventListener('click', missClick);

    const handler = (e) => {
        if (parentDiv.contains(e.target)) {
            alert('miss click');
            document.body.removeEventListener('click', handler);
        }
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('click', handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This website seems to be what you are looking for :)
http://youmightnotneedjquery.com

example `off()` looks more like `el.removeEventListener(eventName, eventHandler);`

`$('body')` would look more like `.getElementByTagName()` or `document.querySelectorAll('whatever selector');`

Comment: My answer is hopefully more of a "teach a person to fish moment" rather than just giving you an answer :)